# get the selected field into textarea using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the selected option from the combobox to appear in the textarea.
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pratik24/QJ6yQ/)

Here is the html:

```
<select id="header-values" multiple="headervalues" style="width:200px" name="headervalues" >
                            <option selected="">MVA</option>
                            <option>Jet Ski</option>
                            <option>Bus Accident</option>
                            <option>Worker's Comp</option>
                            <option>field1</option>
                            <option>field2</option>
                            <option>field3</option>
                        </select>
                        <br>
                        <textarea id="headervalues-log" class="log" class="ui-widget-content"></textarea>
```

once I select any option it showed be inserted into textarea, If I select the option again the next option should appear.

I tried the following code but doesnot work. cant figure out what is wrong,

```
/*$("select, #header-values").change(function(){
        var selecttext =$('#header-values : selected').val();
        var insertText = $(this).text();
        $('#headervalues-log').append(" "+insertText);
    });*/

$("select, #header-values").change(function () {
    var str = "";
    $("select option:selected").each(function () {
        str += $(this).text() + " ";
    });
    $("headervalues-log").text(str);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
$("#header-values").change(function() {
    var selOption = $(this).find(":selected").text();

    $("#headervalues-log").text(selOption);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QJ6yQ/7/

add this line at the end for multiple selection and selecting a field after deleting an entry from the textarea.

```
 $("#headervalues-log").val(function() { 
     return this.value + selOption + ', ' }).prependTo("#headervalues-log");
 });
```

Comment: It can be `var selOption = $(this).find(":selected").val();`

Comment: @passionateCoder -- Changed it to `var selOption = $(this).find(":selected").text();` -- I would use `this.value` for the value.

Comment: Ive seen `this.value` behave weirdly in some older versions of chrome and FF, so i always prefer to search down to the option and use jquery's `.val()`

Comment: Good heads up, I haven't any issues when using it, but i'll know where to look now if I do

Comment: thanks tymeJV your code works properly on JSfiddle. but its not working on my page. something else might be causing the problem. figuring it out.

Comment: got it fixed . works properly. thanks passionateCoder3 and tymeJV.

Comment: this line can be used if multiple selection is required. it also works if you select something after deleted an entry from the textarea  $("#headervalues-log").val(function(){ return this.value + selOption + ', ' }).prependTo("#headervalues-log");

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("select#header-values").change(function () {
    var str = "";
    $("select option:selected").each(function () {
        str += $(this).text() + " ";
    });
    $("#headervalues-log").val(str);
})
```

check it out on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UHhCa/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select and remove from the select box then use the following appendTo api

```
$('select option:selected').remove().appendTo($("#headervalues-log"));
```

Other wise use only appendTo to append

```
$('select option:selected').appendTo($("#headervalues-log"));
```